# How do I dynamically change the ID to do calculations?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the same form duplicated and triplicated, and depending on clicks on a button, they appear. What I want to do is to be able to make calculations, for example, of the cell **Quantity** and **Unit_Price** a multiplication and that the result is reflected in **Total Price**.

**I need the Quantity and Unit_Price IDs to change dynamically** so that the result is displayed per cell in their respective **Total Price**. I already wrote a piece of code that takes the number of each cell, the problem is that I don't know how to put it with the ID so that it is dynamic (the number should change depending on the cell it is in)
This is where I don't know how the code should be:

```js
function multiplicar() {
  let quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('id__form-1-quantity').value);
  let unit_price = document.getElementById('id__form-1-unit_price').value;
  let total_price = document.getElementById('id__form-1-total_price');
  total_price.value = quantity * unit_price;
}

function updateEmptyFormIDs(element, totalForms) {
  var thisInput = element
  var currentName = element.attr('name')
  var newName = currentName.replace(/__prefix__/g, totalForms)

  thisInput.attr('name', newName)
  thisInput.attr('id', "id__" + newName)

  var newFormRow = element.closest(".part-form");

  var newRowId = "row_id_" + newName
  newFormRow.attr("id", newRowId)

  newFormRow.addClass("new-parent-row")
  var parentDiv = element.parent();
  parentDiv.attr("id", "parent_id_" + newName)

  var inputLabel = parentDiv.find("label")
  inputLabel.attr("for", "id_" + newName)

  return newFormRow
}

function addForm() {
  //$('.add-new-form').click(function(e){

  var formId = "id_form-TOTAL_FORMS"
  var emptyRow = $("#empty-row").clone();
  emptyRow.attr("id", null);

  var totalForms = parseInt($('#' + formId).val());

  var newFormRow;
  emptyRow.find("input,select,textarea").each(function() {
    newFormRow = updateEmptyFormIDs($(this), totalForms)
  })

  $(".part-form:last").after(newFormRow)

  $('#' + formId).val(totalForms + 1);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="parent_id_form-1-quantity">
      <input type="number" name="form-1-quantity" class="form-control" id="id__form-1-quantity">
    </td>

    <td id="parent_id_form-1-unit_price">
      <input type="number" name="form-1-unit_price" class="form-control" onchange="multiplicar()" id="id__form-1-unit_price">
    </td>

    <td id="parent_id_form-1-total_price">
      <input type="number" name="form-1-total_price" class="form-control" id="id__form-1-total_price">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please fix up the snippet demo I created so it shows your problem. It looks like you have the right idea. Something minor must be wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand you, I show the code simplified because there are many lines of HTML with Django

Comment: Please see [ask]. You should be able to make this work in simplified form.

Comment: ok i will edit it